# Max string recursion exceeded when using str.format_map()

Tags: python, json, string

I am using [str.format_map](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format_map#str.format_map) to format some strings but I encounter a problem when this string contains quotes, even escaped. Here is the code:

```
class __FormatDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return '{' + key + '}'

def format_dict(node, template_values):
    template_values = __FormatDict(template_values)
    for key, item in node.items():
        if isinstance(item, str):
            node[key] = item.format_map(template_values)
```

For reqular strings (that do not include brackets or quotes) it works, however for strings like `"{\"libraries\":[{\"file\": \"bonjour.so\", \"modules\":[{\"name\": \"hello\"}]}]}"` it crashes with the message `ValueError: Max string recursion exceeded`.

Escaping the quotes using `json.dumps(item)` before formatting it does not solve the issue. What should be done to fix this problem? I am modifying strings I get from JSON files and I would prefer to fix the Python code instead of updating the JSON documents I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use your `__missing__` trick on JSON data. There are multiple problems. That's because the text within `{...}` replacement fields are *not just treated as strings*. Take a look at [the syntax grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> ```
> replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
> field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
> ```

Within a replacement field, `!...` and `:...` have meaning too! What goes into those sections has strict limits as well.

The recursion error comes from the multiple nested `{...}` placeholders inside placeholders inside placeholders; `str.format()` and `str.format_map()` can't support a large number of levels of nesting:

```
>>> '{foo:{baz: {ham}}}'.format_map({'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 's', 'ham': 's'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Max string recursion exceeded
```

but there are other problems here:

- The `:` colon denotes a [formatting specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), which is then passed to the object (key) from the part before the `:`. You'd have to give your `__missing__` return values a wrapper object with `__format__` method if you wanted to recover those.
- Field names with `.` or `[...]` in them have special meaning too; `"bonjour.so"` will be parsed as the `"bonjour` key, with a `so` attribute. Ditto for `[...]` in the field name, but for item lookups.

Those last two can be *approached* by returning a wrapper object with `__format__` and `__getitem__` and `__getattr__` methods, but only in limited cases:

```
>>> class FormatWrapper:
...     def __init__(self, v):
...         self.v = v
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         return '{{{}{}}}'.format(self.v, (':' + spec) if spec else '')
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return FormatWrapper('{}[{}]'.format(self.v, key))
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         return FormatWrapper('{}.{}'.format(self.v, attr))
...
>>> class MissingDict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         return FormatWrapper(key)
...
>>> '{"foo.com": "bar[baz]", "ham": "eggs"}'.format_map(MissingDict())
'{"foo.com": "bar[baz]", "ham": "eggs"}'
>>> '{"foo  .com": "bar [ baz ]", "ham": "eggs"}'.format_map(MissingDict())
'{"foo  .com": "bar [ baz ]", "ham": "eggs"}'
```

This fails for 'empty' attributes:

```
>>> '{"foo...com": "bar[baz]", "ham": "eggs"}'.format_map(MissingDict())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Empty attribute in format string
```

In short, the format makes too many assumptions about what is contained inside `{...}` curly braces, assumptions JSON data easily breaks.

I suggest you look at using the [`string.Template()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) instead, a simpler templating system that can be subclassed; the default is to look for and replace `$identifier` strings. The [`Template.safe_substitute()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template.safe_substitute) does exactly what you want; replace known `$identifier` placeholders, but leave unknown names untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
my_dict = {'outer_key':{"inner1_k1":"iv_some_string_{xyz}"},"inner1_k2":{'inner2_k2':'{abc}'}}
          
s = str(my_dict)
maps = {'{xyz}':'is_cool','{abc}':123}
for k,v in maps.items():
    s = s.replace(f"{k}",str(v))

my_dict = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

- If you are okay with string as value in required dict.